# Keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to read from JSON file

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm trying to read from a json file in order to create visual images via processing. My code so far is:

```
public void generateShape(JSONObject file) {
    //convert file to json object
    JSONArray shapes = (JSONArray) file.get("shapes");
    for (Object o : shapes) {
        JSONObject json_shape = (JSONObject)o;
        //getting shape id and function so we know which shapes to create
        id = ((Number) json_shape.get("id")).intValue();
        func = ((Number) json_shape.get("func")).intValue();
        animate = ((Number) json_shape.get("animate")).intValue();
        stroke_weight = ((Number) json_shape.get("stroke_weight")).floatValue();

        JSONArray strokes = (JSONArray) json_shape.get("stroke");
        Iterator<Float> iterator = strokes.iterator();
        index = 0;
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            stroke[index] = ((Number)iterator.next()).floatValue();
            index++;

        }
```

stoke[] is an array of floats which will control the colour of the stroke.
The json file im parsing from is

```
{
   "shapes": [
{
  "id":0,
  "func":1,
  "stroke":[143,50,200],
  "stroke_weight": 70,
  "animate": 1,
  "jelly_func": 5,
  "points":[268,330,400,333,74,210,90,300]

  }

  ]
}
```

im getting the error at the line:

```
     stroke[index] = ((Number)iterator.next()).floatValue();
```

I'm using the json.simple library and all solutions i've seen are for org.json library

I could hard code the values in the stroke array but I wanted to try iteration instead. Any tips/guidance?

full stack trace is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ImageLoader.generateShape(ImageLoader.java:35)
at Sketch.setup(Sketch.java:48)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2404)
at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:313)
```

where sketch is:

```
 ImageLoader image = new ImageLoader();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONObject file = (JSONObject) parser.parse((new FileReader("save_data.json")));
        image.generateShape(file);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

eta: ok so upon removing the line causing the exception, and checking if my json values are even being read I can confirm the values being parsed are correct when I print them to console. I just now need to put them in an array

Comment: Point at what line does the exception occur.

Comment: Yes, please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: `stroke[]` length should be >= `strokes` size; is it?

Comment: i've edited my post

Comment: does your file only have that 1 shape in there?  if there are more than one shape can you print out the id then post that shape's json ?

Comment: only one shape so far. edited to show line causing error

Comment: did you initialize your stroke anywhere? `float[] stroke = new float[strokes.size()];`

Comment: yup. init it to 10 just to be safe

Comment: Use your debugger, or add System.out.println() traces in the code, to know what is null at that line. It can by stroke, or the value returned by iterator.next(). Act accordingly.

Comment: We can't really help you if we can't see a [mcve]. Also please try to [debug your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I still think you didn't initialize the array right... can you try this code and see if it works?

```
public void generateShape(JSONObject file) {
    // convert file to json object
    JSONArray shapes = (JSONArray) file.get("shapes");
    for (Object o : shapes) {
        JSONObject json_shape = (JSONObject) o;
        // getting shape id and function so we know which shapes to create
        int id = ((Number) json_shape.get("id")).intValue();
        int func = ((Number) json_shape.get("func")).intValue();
        int animate = ((Number) json_shape.get("animate")).intValue();
        float stroke_weight = ((Number) json_shape.get("stroke_weight")).floatValue();

        JSONArray strokes = (JSONArray) json_shape.get("stroke");
        Iterator<Float> iterator = strokes.iterator();
        int index = 0;
        float[] stroke = new float[strokes.size()];
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            stroke[index] = ((Number) iterator.next()).floatValue();
            index++;

        }
    }
}
```